# PRAW - appending output to a list

Tags: praw

I'm trying to edit some code from PRAW so that instead of printing out the comments of a subreddit post, it appends them to a dataframe where it will be used for further analysis.

The original bit of code I am trying to edit is:

```
from praw.models import MoreComments

for i in dat_comments_id:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=i)
    for comment in submission.comments:
        if isinstance(comment, MoreComments):
            continue           
        print(comment.body)
```

What I originally had in mind, which doesn't work was:

```
subreddit_comments = []

for i in dat_comments_id:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=i)
    for comment in submission.comments:
        if isinstance(comment, MoreComments):
            subreddit_comments.append(comment)
```

Rather than give me a list with all the comments, it prints out all the post ids like this:

```
<MoreComments count=591, children=['dmh6ry8', 'dmgt4w1', 'dmgsdrf', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=747, children=['dimdq81', 'dimps03', 'dime3no', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=818, children=['do2y328', 'do2m468', 'do2o35v', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=21, children=['di8cx4x', 'di8380y', 'di826lg', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=370, children=['djk11xc', 'djkfd37', 'djkd0qs', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=591, children=['dmh6ry8', 'dmgt4w1', 'dmgsdrf', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=747, children=['dimdq81', 'dimps03', 'dime3no', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=818, children=['do2y328', 'do2m468', 'do2o35v', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=21, children=['di8cx4x', 'di8380y', 'di826lg', '...']>,
 <MoreComments count=370, children=['djk11xc', 'djkfd37', 'djkd0qs', '...']>]
```

How can I edit the code so that it is appending the original output rather than printing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I stumbled on an answer. I'm still open to better options from anyone more familiar with PRAW.

```
comment_list = []

for i in dat_comments_id:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=i)
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
    for c in submission.comments.list():
        individual_comment = c.body    # This is the line that made the difference
        comment_list.append(individual_comment)
```